# Can't run matplotlib library, error in (The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Unable to co-run code for result. Gives an **error message** [`TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is object.` ].[data set][1]

```
headers = ['Day', 'Hour', 'time', 'T', 'P0', 'P', 'Pa', 'U', 'Ff', 'R', 'Q']
dtypes = {'Day': 'str', 'Hour': 'str', 'time': 'str', 'T': 'float', 'P0': 'float', 'Pa': 'float',
          'U': 'float', 'Ff': 'float', 'R': 'float', 'Q': 'float'}
parse_dates = ['Day', 'Hour', 'time']
points = pandas.read_excel('last.xlsx', sheet_name=1,
                           names=headers, dtype=str, parse_dates=True)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
points.time = pandas.to_datetime(points.time)
points.iloc[:,3:] = points.iloc[:,3:].astype(float)
x = points['time'].values
y = points['T'].values
z = points['Q'].values
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

what am I doing wrong?
[1]: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/JxQBErHf7hptJw

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/error messages. Post the formatted text directly here on SO. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71454712/edit).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)